# Gradle integration test suite depending on testImplementation dependencies

Tags: gradle, jvm

I am trying to migrate to the [test suites](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) introduced in Gradle 7.3. What I'd like to do is to add `testImplementation` dependencies to my integration tests.

```kotlin
testing {
    suites { 
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) { 
            useJUnitJupiter() 
        }

        val integrationTest by registering(JvmTestSuite::class) { 
            dependencies {
                implementation(project) // This adds dependencies to the prod code
                // What to add to automatically use testImplementation deps?
            }
            ...
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We tried to use JvmTestSuite and it appeared that it brings much more problems than it solves. I strongly recommend to just set up separate test tasks manually. Like it's described here (Beware that gradle examples are also incomplete):
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You’d probably like to make the `integrationTestImplementation` configuration extend the `testImplementation` configuration – just like `testImplementation` already extends `implementation` by default. See also the docs on [configuration inheritance](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:config-inheritance-composition).

Here’s a self-contained example (tested with Gradle 7.3.2):

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

testing {
    suites { 
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) { 
            useJUnitJupiter() 
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.21.0")
            }
        }

        val integrationTest by registering(JvmTestSuite::class) { 
            dependencies {
                // TODO add any integration test only dependencies here
            }
        }
    }
}

// Here’s the bit that you’re after:
val integrationTestImplementation by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
}
```

If you run `./gradlew dependencies --configuration integrationTestRuntimeClasspath` *with* the configuration inheritance configured, then you’ll get the following output (abbreviated):

```
integrationTestRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'integration test'.
+--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2
|    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2
|    |    …
|    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2
|    |    …
|    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2
|    |    …
|    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2
|         …
\--- org.assertj:assertj-core:3.21.0
```

However, if you run the same command *without* the configuration inheritance, then you’ll get the following output (abbreviated) – note the missing `org.assertj:assertj-core:3.21.0` dependency:

```
integrationTestRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'integration test'.
\--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2
     +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2
     |    …
     +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2
     |    …
     +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2
     |    …
     \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2
```

---

As requested in the answer comments, here’s additionally one way of making a test data class from the unit test suite available for integration testing:

```kotlin
sourceSets.named("integrationTest") {
    java {
        val sharedTestData = project.objects.sourceDirectorySet("testData",
                "Shared test data")
        sharedTestData.srcDir("src/test/java")
        sharedTestData.include("com/example/MyData.java")
        source(sharedTestData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. One more thing, I have a  class in my `test` sources and I'd like to access it from the `integrationTests`. How can I add this dependency?

Comment: I’m not sure if such a dependency would be a good idea. If you added the `test` classes to the `integrationTest` classpath, then it would probably mean that normal unit test suites (from `test`) would also be run (again) when the integration tests are run. IMHO, a better approach would be to add such test-only classes to a separate subproject which can then be made an `implementation` dependency of both `test` and `integrationTest`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Interesting, it's not happening when implemented the "old" way without test suites. We have for example TestData class which we want to share and extracting it to a module is an overkill.

Comment: Yeah, it’s definitely possible with some file tree filtering; see also my updated answer. It’s arguable, though, if that’s more maintainable than having a separate submodule. In the best case at least, the submodule approach would even require less lines of code (one line for the `include()` in the `settings.gradle.kts`, three for applying the `java-library` plugin in the new submodule and one for making the subproject a dependency of the `test` suite).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with following solution

```kotlin
testing {
    suites { 
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) { 
            useJUnitJupiter() 
        }

        val integrationTest by registering(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            useJUnitJupiter()

            dependencies {
                implementation(project)
                // add testImplementation dependencies
                configurations.testImplementation {
                    dependencies.forEach(::implementation)
                }
            }

            sources {
                java {
                    //...
                }
            }

            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        shouldRunAfter(test)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Gradle Dev, currently working on this incubating feature.

One thing to keep in mind is that while currently the names of the configurations created for each test suite are based on the name of the corresponding `sourceSet`, which matches the name of the Test Suite itself, *these names should be treated as an implementation detail*.  One of the main goals of Test Suites is to build a useful layer of abstraction over these details, and allow you to configure them without detailed knowledge of this sort of plumbing.

Wiring the configurations together with `extendsFrom` goes against this intent, as does any sort of retrieval by name, and should be seen as anti-patterns.

Better options include using `suites.withType(JvmTestSuite).configureEach { suite -> ... }` or creating a `Closure` containing the configuration you want and using it to configure the test suites of interest like this:

```
testing {
    suites {
        def applyMockitoAndJupiter = { suite -> 
            suite.useJUnitJupiter()
            suite.dependencies {
                implementation('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.6.1')
            }
        }

        /* This is the equivalent of:
            test {
                applyMockitoAndJupiter(this)
            }
         */
        test(applyMockitoAndJupiter) 

        /* This is the equivalent of:
            integrationTest(JvmTestSuite)
            applyMockitoAndJupiter(integrationTest)
         */
        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite, applyMockitoAndJupiter) 
    }
}
```

We're working to expand the functionality offered by Test Suites and each suite's `dependencies` block, as well as to make the docs more explicit about this point as well.  You can see a preview (subject to further change) of this advice in a [future version of the Gradle docs](https://builds.gradle.org/repository/download/Gradle_Master_Check_BuildDistributions/53238069:id/distributions/gradle-7.6-docs.zip!/gradle-7.6-20220623195117%2B0000/docs/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#sharing_configuration_between_multiple_test_suites) - you'll have to log in as guest.

Comment: is there any documentation as to why this whole separated dependency declaration is even considered a better practice? We've been used to this pattern since day 1 of gradle and now a artificial abstraction is introduced making each build file much more complicated than it needs to be, especially if you think about convinience plugins that hide all the boilerplace of declaring such a test suite and the dev is only declaring additional dependencies.

Comment: so how should we provide all `implementation` dependencies of the main build to `integrationTest` without repeating them all?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for not to rewrite the same dependencies twice for `test` and `customTest` tasks. Maybe it is not recommended as per @Tom Tresansky, but I find it quite convenient:

```
    configurations {
        customTestImplementation {
            extendsFrom testImplementation
        }
        customTestCompileOnly {
            extendsFrom testCompileOnly
        }
        customTestAnnotationProcessor {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }
```