# gradle testsuite does not make all project dependencies available to integration tests

Tags: gradle

My integration tests do not have access to e.g. these packages but my normal tests do, why?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.springframework.data
```

Interestingly other packages are available such as

```
import com.mycompany.backend.foo
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException
```

This is my test setup using gradle 8.3 and spring boot. And I think that `implementation(project())` in the `configureEach` block should make them accessible to integration tests.

```
testing {
  suites {
    val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) {
      targets {
        all {
          testTask.configure {
            finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)
            filter {
              isFailOnNoMatchingTests = false
              excludeTestsMatching("*Integration*Test")
              excludeTestsMatching("*.integration.*")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    configureEach {
      if (this is JvmTestSuite) {
        useJUnitJupiter()
        dependencies {
          implementation(project())
          implementation(project(":my-testutils"))
        }
        targets {
          all {
            testTask.configure {
              minHeapSize = "512m"
              maxHeapSize = "2G"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    register<JvmTestSuite>("integrationTest") {
      targets {
        sources {
          kotlin {
            setSrcDirs(listOf("src/testIntegration/kotlin"))
          }
        }
        all {
          testTask.configure {
            shouldRunAfter(test)
            finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)
            filter {
              isFailOnNoMatchingTests = false
              includeTestsMatching("*.integration.*")
              includeTestsMatching("*IntegrationTest")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the build script sample you provided we cannot see the dependencies of the project itself, but we can guess it depends on `spring-data-jpa` in `implementation` configuration, so let's assume you have this dependency as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:$springDataVersion")
    // other project deps
}
```

Then you try to reference classes from this `spring-data-jpa` library in your *test* and *integrationTest* suite classes.

Here is a simple build setup to reproduce and explain why you can reference `spring-data-jpa` from the *test* suite classes but not from *integrationTest* suite ones:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:$springDataVersion")
    // other project deps
}

testing {
    suites {
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            // (1)
            // this test suite dependencies are already configured by default, through application of the Java plugin,
            // see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management
        }
        register<JvmTestSuite>("integrationTest") {
            targets {
                // srcDirs configuration ...
            }
        }
        configureEach {
            if (this is JvmTestSuite) {
                useJUnitJupiter()
                dependencies {
                    // (2)
                    // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#configure_dependencies_of_a_test_suite_to_reference_project_outputs
                    //  Quote: " Configure a new test suite which adds a project() dependency to the suite’s compile and runtime classpaths.
                    //           This dependency provides access to the project’s outputs as well as any dependencies
                    //           declared on its api and compileOnlyApi configurations.
                    /// "
                    implementation(project())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup:

- (1) *test* suite `testImplementation` configuration extends `implementation`, so you can reference  the project’s outputs as well as any dependencies declared on its `implementation` configurations
  ==> *spring data* classes are available *test* classes compile scope,
- (2) as describer in 'bullet (3)' in this section from the Gradle doc: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#configure_dependencies_of_a_test_suite_to_reference_project_outputs :

> This dependency provides access to the project’s outputs as well as any dependencies declared on its api and compileOnlyApi configurations.

==> `spring-data-jpa` is not declared in the `api` nor `compileOnlyApi` configuration in main project, so you won't inherit this library classes in your `integrationTest` classpath.

See this discussion in the Gradle forum which deals with this "issue", and provides some solutions you could try: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/7-3-test-suite-inherit-test-libraries-for-integration-test/41980/1

**EDIT**

From the discussion I linked above, you can see that there is currently no way to create the missing dependencies using the Test Suite DSL ; you will have to create these dependency manually: one simple way is to make `integrationTestImplementation` configuration "inherit" (extendsFrom) the main  `implementation` configuration as follows:

```
configurations.named("integrationTestImplementation").configure {
    this.extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}
```

This way, `integrationTest` compile classpath with inherit the main sourceset compile classpath including all project dependencies defined in `implementaiton` configuration.

You could also inherit from `testImplementation` configuration, if you want to access `test` dependencies (e.g. test frameworks like mockito or others) from your integration test classes:

```
configurations.named("integrationTestImplementation").configure {
    this.extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
}
```

Comment: I now better understand the problem, but the linked discussion does not really give a solution. How can I make the dependencies of the project available without re-mentioning them all manually in the test suite dependencies and without setting them to `api` instead of `implementation`?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a working solution based on hints found in the forum discussion I pointed out. not sure their are better ways to do that in latest Gradle 8 version, using Test Suite DSL.

Comment: mhhh extending is an anti-pattern as said by the gradle dev here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72792136/386201

Comment: @Stuck yeah it might look as an anti-pattern, as said by the Gradle guy in this comment more than 1 year ago; but he provided no real solution to avoid repeating manually main dependencies to each test suite dependencies, and he also did not explain this "by design"  choice to make only `api` and `compileOnly`from prod code available in test suite code. so the current proposed solution, looks like a "only-available-pattern" solution, until we have a better way proposed by Gradle team.

Comment: ok thanks for the follow ups. I will roll with this one for now, but keep it the question open for potential better solutions in the future