# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [root project ..]

Tags: gradle

It seems that you are trying to migrate your test suite from `unbroken` to the new `gradle testsuite` introduced in Gradle 7.4, but you are encountering some issues with your multi-build setup.

```
testing {
    suites {
        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            implementation project // ALSO TRIED -> implementation subprojects
            testType = TestSuiteType.INTEGRATION_TEST

        }
        functionalTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            testType = TestSuiteType.FUNCTIONAL_TEST

        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
    functionalTestImplementation.extendsFrom integrationTestImplementation
    functionalTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}
```

I expected to be able to use classes from the main module in all other modules such as test, integrationTest, and so on. However, it seems that this is only possible in the test module and not in integrationTest or other suites.

Is there a specific reason for this limitation? Is there a way to overcome this issue and access classes from the main in integrationtest as well? Any insights or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: see this answer, which explains some limitation with the TestSuite classpath inheritance between main module and test suite modules : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77225649/6899896

Comment: Already tried configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
    functionalTestImplementation.extendsFrom integrationTestImplementation
    functionalTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
} :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like adding `sources` do the job :/

```
testing {
    suites {
        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            testType = TestSuiteType.INTEGRATION_TEST
            sources {
                compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.compileClasspath + sourceSets.main.output
                runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath
            }

        }
        functionalTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            testType = TestSuiteType.FUNCTIONAL_TEST

        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
    functionalTestImplementation.extendsFrom integrationTestImplementation
    functionalTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}
    sources {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.compileClasspath + sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath
    }
```