# How to configure Gradle JVM test suites for integration tests?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, integration-testing

I want to add an integration test suite to a Kotlin project using [Gradle's JVM Test Suites](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#configure_dependencies_of_a_test_suite), but it cannot compile the tests because of missing dependencies. How do I need to point the integration tests to the regular tests' dependencies?

The project structure (generated by `gradle init`, plus my added `src/intTest`) looks like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src
│       ├── intTest
│       │   └── kotlin
│       │       └── SomeTest.kt
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── kotlin
│       │   │   └── mcve
│       │   │       └── App.kt
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           ├── kotlin
│           │   ├── SomeTest.kt
│           │   └── mcve
│           │       └── AppTest.kt
│           └── resources
├── gradle
│   ├── libs.versions.toml
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

`app/src/test/kotlin/SomeTest.kt` and `app/src/intTest/kotlin/SomeTest.kt` are the same file for this MCVE.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import kotlin.test.Test

class SomeTest {
    @Test
    fun someTest() {
        assertEquals(1, 1)
    }
}
```

I've added the new test suite in `app/build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.jvm)
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")
}

testing {
    suites {
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            useKotlinTest("1.9.20")
        }
        // Added the new test suite here:
        val intTest by registering(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project())
            }
        }
    }
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))
    }
}

application {
    mainClass.set("mcve.AppKt")
}
```

When I run `./gradlew test`, it works, but when I run `./gradlew intTest`, it fails because it cannot find neither the production dependency (coroutines) nor the test dependencies (ktest):

```
> Task :app:compileIntTestKotlin FAILED
e: file:///Users/robert/mcve/app/src/intTest/kotlin/SomeTest.kt:1:8 Unresolved reference: kotlinx
e: file:///Users/robert/mcve/app/src/intTest/kotlin/SomeTest.kt:1:15 Unresolved reference: test
e: file:///Users/robert/mcve/app/src/intTest/kotlin/SomeTest.kt:2:15 Unresolved reference: test
e: file:///Users/robert/mcve/app/src/intTest/kotlin/SomeTest.kt:5:6 Unresolved reference: Test
e: file:///Users/robert/mcve/app/src/intTest/kotlin/SomeTest.kt:7:9 Unresolved reference: assertEquals

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileIntTestKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

How do I need to configure Gradle 8.5 (Revision     28aca86a7180baa17117e0e5ba01d8ea9feca598) to run the integration tests in `app/src/intTest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are separate reasons why the Kotlin test library and the main source set dependencies are not being passed to the integration test suite.

##### Adding the Kotlin test library

Calling `useKotlinTest()` adds dependencies, but only to the suite it is called on. Therefore you need to call it for every test suite. This appears to be a bug in the test suites feature<sup>1</sup>.

You can configure for all suites by using:

```
testing {
    suites {
        withType<JvmTestSuite>().configureEach {
            useKotlinTest("1.9.20")
        }
    }
}
```

##### Depending on the main project dependencies

Calling `implementation(project())` does not add a dependency on the main source set's compile dependency configurations<sup>2</sup>.

One way to add these in is to make the new test suite's `implementation` configuration extend the `implementation` configuration of the main source set:

```
val intTest by registering(JvmTestSuite::class) {
    dependencies {
        implementation(project())
    }
    configurations {
        named(sources.implementationConfigurationName) {
            extendsFrom(getByName(JavaPlugin.IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIGURATION_NAME))
        }
    }
}
```

This topic is also discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77224717/gradle-testsuite-does-not-make-all-project-dependencies-available-to-integration).

---

<sup>1</sup>The configuration of test frameworks is covered in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#sec:declare_an_additional_test_suite) where it says in footnote 4:

> You do not have to explicitly configure the testing framework on these additional suites, unless you wish to change to another framework

This suggests it should be sufficient to configure the framework for the main test suite, as you have. Having tested it myself, I agree with you that in the case of the Kotlin test framework it does not, contrary to the documentation, add the necessary dependencies to additional test suites.

<sup>2</sup>This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#configure_dependencies_of_a_test_suite_to_reference_project_outputs) in footnote 3:

> [The `project()`] dependency provides access to the project’s outputs as well as any dependencies declared on its `api` and `compileOnlyApi` configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Spot on for the test library, but I get a compiler error `Unresolved reference: extendsFrom` when I try to reuse the main dependencies inside the `testing` block. I've probably been staring at this for too long.

Comment: Ok, I can change my main `dependencies` block to say `api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")` instead of `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")`. Not sure if this has other implications if I'm not creating an API jar, but that at least does compile my integration tests.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out: turns out I was using some functionality that the Kotlin plugin I had applied was adding to the buildscript classpath. Now updated to use regular Gradle methods. Yes agreed that adding to `api` solves the problem in many cases, but not if you're publishing a library and it's important what functionality you're making available to consumers

Comment: Yes, good points about the use of `api`. Thanks for the update, works as expected!